# multiple nested functions output

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to get the result of multiple functions as nested functions from a dataframe

For example, 2 functions:

```
def carr(df):
    df['carr'] = df[['end_value_carr','arr']].max(axis=1)
    return df
```

```
def date(df):
    df['date_id'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_id']).dt.date
    df['renewal_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['renewal_date']).dt.date
    df['next_renewal_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['next_renewal_date']).dt.date
    return df
```

When I use each one separately I get the right output

However, trying to have them nested in one function gives me a NoneType:

```
def cleanup(data):
    df = data.copy()
    def carr(df):
        df['carr'] = df[['end_value_carr','arr']].max(axis=1)
        return df
    def date(df):
        df['date_id'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_id']).dt.date
        df['renewal_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['renewal_date']).dt.date
        df['next_renewal_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['next_renewal_date']).dt.date
        return df
    return df
```

Appreciate your help!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define all three functions separately

```
def carr(df):
    df['carr'] = df[['end_value_carr','arr']].max(axis=1)
    return df

def date(df):
    df['date_id'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_id']).dt.date
    df['renewal_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['renewal_date']).dt.date
    df['next_renewal_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['next_renewal_date']).dt.date
    return df
```

Call the first two functions in your third one.

```
def cleanup(data):
    df = data.copy()
    df = carr(df)
    df = date(df)
    return df
```

Then you can call your `cleanup` function, which will call `carr` and `date` on its own.

```
df = cleanup(df)
```